# Creating base R plots in loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Trying to create a set of base R plots (one plot for each unique ID) in a loop and am having some issues. I've looked at a few different other questions and haven't yet found a solution that works for me. Here is what my code looks like:

```
# Data
test <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Year = c(1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988), Amount = c(123,155,11,18,20,25,30,55,80))
test$Year <- as.Date(as.character(test$Year), format = "%Y")

for(i in unique(test$ID)){

  title.text <- toupper(paste0("ID number", i,"\n"))
  title.subtext <- toupper(paste0("This is a graph"))

  linedata <- data.frame("Amount" = test[[i]]$Amount, "Year" = test[[i]]$Year)

  png(paste0("C:/path/", i, "_loads.png",sep=""), width=1100,   height=950, units="px", res=150)
  par(mar=c(8,4,4,2)+0.1)
  options(scipen=5)

  plot(linedata$Amount~linedata$Year, type = "l", pch=17, col = "#B53737", xlab = "", ylab = "",
       main = "")

  title(ylab="Y axis title", line=2, cex.lab=1.1)
  title(xlab="X axis title", line=2.7, cex.lab=1.1)

  title(title.text, cex.main = 1.0)
  mtext(title.subtext, cex=0.8)

  dev.off()

}

# Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
#  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'linedata$Amount'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are problems in `data.frame("Amount" = test[[i]]$Amount, "Year" = test[[i]]$Year)`. First, it's `data.frame(var=...)`, without quote. And `test[[i]]` is not a dataframe from which you can take the variable `Account`: `test[[i]]` is a vector that contains the ith column of `test`.

Comment: Try  `linedata <- data.frame(Amount=test[test$ID == i, ]$Amount, Year=test[test$ID == i, ]$Year)` in for loop.

Comment: Thanks, folks. @jay.sf - your solution worked. If you add it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just a minor issue in how you subset the data in your `for` loop, then it should work.

```
for(i in unique(test$ID)){

  [...]

  linedata <- 
    data.frame(Amount=test[test$ID == i, ]$Amount, Year=test[test$ID == i, ]$Year)

  [...]

}
```